# Two extensions or one?

Tags: firefox-addon

If the firefox extension implements two different functionalities is it better to implement it as two extensions or to create one extension with both functionalities? Is there some speed advantage if you have fewer extensions?

Comment: Imagine that you have an extension with 20 javascript functions. Half of them do one functionality the the other half do some logically independent functionality. I feel that it could be better to make two extensions. Is there a reason to leave everything in one extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some perf cost associated with more extensions (e.g. slightly more I/O on startup), but it's rather small, especially when compared with things the extensions do.

If you're curious, you could [measure what the difference is for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Measuring_Add-on_Startup_Performance#Using_about%3astartup). I expect < 50ms on warm startup on a modern machine and for cold startup it's just one more file (assuming you don't set em:unpack) in addition to a couple dozen other files Firefox touches on startup.

I say, go with separate extensions if it's a public extension: most people will probably use just one of them. If it's just something for yourself, then it doesn't matter, in my opinion.